# Node.js express, timeout "Can\'t set headers after they are sent."

Tags: node.js, express, timeout

I have some really strange problem with nodejs and express.

One of my functions that handles request, have to get something from DB and send it as JSON to client.

So it goes like this:

1. Get request
2. Call DB
3. Process data and pack it to JSON
4. response.json(JSON)

Normally it will go all OK but if there is timeout between 2 and 3 because it is asynchronously it will automatically create response and there will be error "Can\'t set headers after they are sent." when I call 4

Does anyone else have this problem? Is there any normal way to handle it or I just have to check if response._header is allready set?

```
exports.appstimebygroup = function (req, res) {
    var resp = {};
    var clientId = Webapi.extractClientId(req);

    AppTime.getByGroupId(clientId, req.body.groupId, function(error, appstime){
        if (error) {
            handleError(error);
            resp.returnCode = 0;
            resp.message = "Some error have happened, please contact support!";
            res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            res.json(resp);
            return;
        }

        resp.returnCode = 1;
        resp.appstime = appstime;

        if(res._header){
            console.log("header allready set!");
            return;
        }

        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.json(resp);
    });
};
```

And AppTime.getByGroupId has asynchronous call inside.

Comment: My guess is that you are not waiting for your async requests to complete first before sending a response, so you're trying to send a response twice to the same request. Post the relevant code and we can know for sure.

Comment: I added the code. But As I already described there is not problem in code. Problem is in timeout, because timeout happens in the middle of the asynchronous call and then express sets header and send it. And when call is finished my function try to do it again. I can also repeat this error standalone.

Comment: I don't immediately see anything wrong here. What does `handleError` do? Also, why are you setting the `Content-Type` header? `res.json` already does this for you -> [LINK](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/12f92a50dc59887c30f4c6f23fdfbfc616dcbef5/lib/response.js#L232)

Comment: I wasn't sure about Content-Type so I added it manually. handleError just write error.stack with red letters nothing special. As I described, problem is only when timeout is triggered while nodejs is waiting for DB and headers are automatically sent.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem is multipart-form-data handling timeout.

When that happens it calls next(err).

```
  form.on('error', function(err){
    if (!options.defer) {
      err.status = 400;
      next(err);
    }
    done = true;
  });
```

By default on error it will do res.send(400) and when normally gets to code that you wanted to be executed there is problem.